# Integers summing to a given number in R

Tags: r, combinatorics

I’m looking to create, in R, a matrix with m columns, such that the elements of each row are non-negative integers which sum to a given n. There must be as many rows as there are ways to do the arrangement. I can only think of some complex ways to do that, so before starting to reinvent the wheel I was wondering: is there a simple magic way to do this in a couple of lines?

Comment: You want all [combinations](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/combn.html) of integers that its sum is a given number?

Comment: Any restrictions on `m` and `n`, i.e., do you need a method for if those are large?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Llopis comment, I came up with the following function that does the job:

```
eq_sum <- function(m,n){
  comb <- expand.grid(replicate(m, 0:n, simplify=FALSE))
  delete <- seq(nrow(comb))*(rowSums(comb)!=n)
  comb[-delete,]
}
```

I guess it's not the most efficient since it calculates all the combinations and just takes a tiny subset at the end. However it should be enough for my purposes.

Comment: Use `rowSums(comb)` instead of `apply(comb,1,sum)`.

Comment: shouldn't it be 1:n? given your question states " positive integers".